# Is it possible to create pdf file by naming it as .pdf in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pdf

I am using SVN via eclipse. Now I have to commit a pdf file and I am wondering if I can make it by making a file and naming it as XXX.pdf. I usually have made txt files in this way, but I am not sure if pdf files can work in this way too?
I appreciate your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It doesn't work that way.